# OCO order Binance, 'symbol' was not sent

Tags: websocket, trading, binance

I am trying to send an OCO order to Binance, but I get "'symbol' was not sent", despite of the fact that I send it. See attached screenshot. Any idea of what am I doing wrong?[See attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH9XL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The return response of the API request says the URL is malformed, please try send again the request but now add the `&` after of `side=SELL` parameter, like this `...side=SELL&type=OCO....`.

Comment: thanks to Enrique it works. But now I have this error "Not all sent parameters were read; read '9' parameter(s) but was sent '10'.\"   and this is my call /api.binance.com/api/v3/order/oco?&symbol=BTCUSDT&side=SELL&type=OCO&quantity=1&price=36000&stopPrice=36100&recvWindow=20000&timestamp=1628457187489&signature=cce21cd283f893489ec90781894568107de34cf398bf3ef8f74a8c962ebe7360

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://dev.binance.vision/t/create-order-not-all-sent-parameter-were-read-code-1104/1238/9

Comment: No, that's not a “LOT_SIZE”  problem. I use Buy or Sell and it works well. The problem is that (It says) im sending 10 parameters and only 9 are readable. But when i look at my script i see only 9 parameters. Not 10.